# Javascript date parse error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, ecmascript-6

```
  let date = new Date("2017-09-12T12:00:00");
  console.log(date.getUTCMonth());
```

Here I am expecting it would log **09** for a month but it's logging **08**.
Year, day , hour and minute gets parsed correctly though. what's going on here? How can I extract 09 from the above date string?

Comment: Javascript month start with 0 which mean January is 0, February is 1, so on. So, you have to add 1 to date.getUTCMonth().

Comment: So day starts from 1 but month starts from 0?

Comment: yes bro, days start from 1 and month for 0 to 11.

Comment: Yes. Only month starts with 0 but day starts with 1.

Comment: Got it new to javascript! :) Thanx guys

Comment: month will start with `0` .So, you have to +1 in month

Comment: You should not be using *getUTCMonth*. The string (if parsed correctly) will be treated as local, not UTC, so *getUTCMonth* may return a different month to *getMonth* unless the host timezone offset is +00:00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getUTCMonth()` is a zero-based value — zero is January.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth

Answer (score 3):

`date.getUTCMonth()` method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date.

So to get what you expect, you should add 1.

Answer (score 2):

Months are 0-indexed in Javascript.

```
var date = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + date.getDate(),
    year = date.getFullYear();
```

For a quick example is how you would format it if you wanted to format it in a YYYY - MM - DD format.